# HighCharts Dynamically add flags

Tags: highcharts

How do I dynamically add flags to a stockchart? This is what I have so far:

```
chart.addSeries([{
        name: 'Events',
        title:'Events',
                        data: [],
                        type: 'flags',
                        shape: 'circlepin',
                        width: 32
    }]);
```

On click of a button, I am trying to add flags:

```
eventSeries.addPoint([{ x: dateToAdd, title: 'Hover', text: 'Event for ' + dateToAdd }], true);
```

Here is the entire example: http://jsfiddle.net/utz5uL3d/2/.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, posting here for completeness. It was my bad that I was passing an array to addPoint:

```
eventSeries.addPoint({ x: dateToAdd, title: 'Hover', text: 'Event for ' + dateToAdd }, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utz5uL3d/5/